# Firebase and illegal invocation

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firebase, runtime-error

Does any one know why i get an illegal invocation error with this code? I think it is because I am trying to inject a profile image into the object that im getting - in the line `addedCard.image = userInfo.image;` but I dont know how to fix it. And because its part of a firebase listener its a continuous loop of errors and they keep adding up. This is the code that I have:

My service:

```
service.cardAdded = function(cb){
        // if(target === "all"){
            if($rootScope.validID){
            prayersRef.orderByChild("group").equalTo($localStorage.seedUser.id).on('child_added', function(snapshot){
                var val = snapshot.val();

                cb.call(this, {
                    to: val.to,
                    from: val.from,
                    date: val.date,
                    assigned: val.assigned,
                    group: val.group,
                    passage: val.passage,
                    id: snapshot.key()
                });
            });
        }
};
```

My controller:

```
myService.cardAdded(function(addedCard){
        $scope.card.push(addedCard);
          ProfileService.retrieveName(addedCard.assigned,function(userInfo) {
            if (userInfo.image) {
              addedCard.image = userInfo.image;  //I think that this is causing the error
            };
          });
      });
```

this is the error:

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
at isArrayLike (angular.js:266)
at forEach (angular.js:322)
at copy (angular.js:832)
at copy (angular.js:798)
at copy (angular.js:838)
at copy (angular.js:798)
at copy (angular.js:820)
at copy (angular.js:790)
at copy (angular.js:838)
at copy (angular.js:798)
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11706
(anonymous     function) @ angular.js:8619
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16417
completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:4940
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5328
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This guidance from the AngularJS might be useful:

> > Lower-level DOM manipulation from your JS code ... is no-no with AngularJS

and

> > If you stick to manipulating data model angular.copy will work just fine.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8353

Your code is calling angular.copy implicitly (you can see that in your Chrome error) so make sure you are only copying you data model, not whole DOM elements.

Have you tried assigning only the elements that you need from the userInfo.image to addedCard.image, instead of copying the whole object, like this?

```
addCard.image = new Card(userInfo.image);

function AddCard(userImage) {
  var obj = {     
    // Assign the needed attributes
  };
  return obj; 
}
```

Comment: im getting the whole card to display, but in the process only getting the image to add to the card (to show user ownership)...I dont quite understand what they are saying in the link you provided; any guidance?

Comment: I've edited my answer above to provide a little more detail. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i must be missing something...isnt this what im doing?? Sorry, im having a hard time seeing the difference

Comment: The difference is what all is contained inside the addCard.image when Angular copies it.

The assignment " addedCard.image = userInfo.image;  " is copying everything in the userInfo.image object into the addedCard.image object. I don't know what's in that object, but if there's DOM attributes, that can cause Angular to throw the error you're seeing. (Can you use the Chrome JavaScript debugger to see the attributes of addedCard.info ?)

Comment: how do you get around that